# Node.js Express.js sslforfree not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https, ssl-certificate

I am using sslforfree for creating an https server with node.js, express.js. But whenever I try to access https://localhost it shows me **error 403: access denied**. My folder structure like this. [image]

and my server.js goes here

```
var express = require('express')
, fs = require('fs')
, passport = require('passport')
, logger = require('mean-logger')
, http = require('http')
, https = require('https')
, path = require('path')
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'
, config = require('./config/config')[env]
, auth = require('./config/middlewares/authorization')
, mongoose = require('mongoose')


var db = mongoose.connect(config.db)

var models_path = __dirname + '/app/models'
fs.readdirSync(models_path).forEach(function (file) {
   require(models_path+'/'+file)
})

require('./config/passport')(passport, config)

var app = express()

require('./config/express')(app, config, passport)

require('./config/routes')(app, passport, auth)


var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,'config/ssl/patarboi.key')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,'config/ssl/patarboi.crt')),
  ca: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,'config/ssl/patarboi.ca'))
};

/*app.listen(port)
console.log('Express app started on port '+port)*/
logger.init(app, passport, mongoose)

// expose app
exports = module.exports = app
var port = process.env.PORT || 443

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
server.listen(port, function () {
 console.log('server at port '+port);
});
```

Comment: try changing port to something like `8080`

Comment: thanks @GeorgeBailey. That kind of works. But I don't know how. Can you explain why port 443 doesn't work?

Comment: let me state that as answer

Comment: if that resolves your issue you can accept and upvote the answer

Comment: You have an SSL certificate for `localhost` ?

Comment: No, actually. Is that the reason you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run your server on port `443`. Remember your service needs to have root permission to listen to this PORT.

And most probably `443` will be in use already.  You can check by `netstat -a` and see if `443` is in the list.

In windows, if you're using skype. This would also create some trouble when you try to use `443` PORT.